# NoMethodError in RelationshipsController#edit undefined method `decorate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, decorator, nomethoderror

So I know where the problem is, but I'm fairly new to ROR and don't know how to work out what methods are available/which variables I should be using.

What I'm trying to do:

a user should be directed to views/relationship/edit when they press 'edit relationship'. 
the variables should correspond so the edit relationship page deals with an accepted, pending or requested relationship between the current_user and the person they're trying to connect to (followed)

1. if a relationship exists in any state, show the edit button. (works)
2. click edit button (this is where the error comes up)
3. show edit page for the relationship between current user and person theyre trying to connect to. (where can accept/delete request)

i don't know why it's saying there is no decorator method - it was working before..

error:

```
NoMethodError in RelationshipsController#edit
undefined method `decorate' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #71):

    # @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]).decorate
    @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:id])
    @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @followed).decorate
  end
```

view/users/index:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <ul>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <li>
                <%= user.name %>
                <div id="relationship-status">
                    <% if current_user.following.include?(@followed) || current_user.pending_following.include?(user) || current_user.requested_following.include?(user) %>
                        <%= link_to "Edit Relationship", edit_relationship_path(followed_id: @followed, id: current_user.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                        followed: <%= @followed %>
                        current_user: <%= current_user.id %>
                        relationship: <%= @relationship %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= link_to "Add Relationship", new_relationship_path(follower_id: user.id), class: "btn btn-primary", id: 'add-relationship', data: { followed_id: user.id.to_param } %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

relationships_controller:

```
  def edit
    # @followed = @relationship.followed
    # @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]).decorate
    @followed = User.find(name: params[:id])
    @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @followed).decorate
  end
```

views/relationship/edit:

```
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Viewing Relationship</h1>
    </div>

    <h3><%= @relationship.sub_message %></h3>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <% if @relationship.requested? %>
            <%= form_for @relationship, url: accept_relationship_path(@relationship), method: :put do |form| %>
                <%= submit_tag "Accept Relationship", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <%= form_for @relationship, url: relationship_path(@relationship), method: :delete do |form| %>
        <%= submit_tag "Delete Relationship", class: 'btn btn-danger' %>

<% end %>
```

model/user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pending_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_many :active_relationships,   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                    dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                    dependent:   :destroy                                
  has_many :following, -> { where(relationships: { state: "accepted" } ) }, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower                              
  has_many :pending_following, -> { where(relationships: { state: "pending" } ) }, through: :pending_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :requested_following, -> { where(relationships: { state: "requested" } ) }, through: :pending_relationships,  source: :followed

...

 # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollow a user. 
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Return true if the current user is following the other user. 
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

  def pending_following?(user)
    pending_following.include?(user)
  end

  def requested_following?(user)
    pending_following.include?(user)
  end
```

user db table:
[image: user db table]

relationship controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:new, :create, :index, :accept, :edit, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :json

  def new
    if params[:followed_id]
      @followed = User.find(params[:followed_id])
      @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.new(followed: @followed)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Relationship required"
    end

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    render 'public/404', status: :not_found
  end

  def create
    if params[:relationship] && params[:relationship].has_key?(:followed_id)
      @followed = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
      # @followed = User.where(name: params[:relationship][:followed_id]).first
      @relationship = Relationship.request(current_user, @followed)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @relationship.new_record?
          format.html do
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem creating that relationship request"
            redirect_to followed_path(@followed)
          end
          format.json { render json: @relationship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed }
        else
          format.html do
            flash[:success] = "Friend request sent"
            redirect_to followed_path(@followed)
          end
          format.json { render json: @relationship.to_json }
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Friend Required"
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  # def create
  #   if params[:followed_id]
  #     @followed = User.find(params[:followed_id])
  #     current_user.follow(@followed)
  #     redirect_to user
  #   else 
  #     flash[:danger] = "else statement"
  #   end
  # end

  def accept
    @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id])
    if @relationship.accept!
      flash[:success] = "You are now connected with #{@relationship.followed.name}"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "That connection could not be accepted."
    end
    redirect_to relationships_path
  end

  def index
    @relationships = current_user.active_relationships.all
    @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    #orig
    # @followed = @relationship.followed
    # @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]).decorate

    #2nd
    # @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:id])
    # @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @followed).decorate

    # stack
    # @followed = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    # @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @followed).decorate

    #stack2
    @followed = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(follower_id: @followed.id).decorate
  end

  def destroy
   ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding **users by name** but passing **"ID"**  for the condition, so it is not able to retrieve corresponding records. Change this and Try Once:

```
 def edit
    # @followed = @relationship.followed
    # @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]).decorate
    @followed = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(follower_id: @followed.id).decorate
  end
```

**Update:**

You have specified `follower_id` as foreign key for your pending relationships try the above edit method. I have updated it.

Comment: 'TypeError in RelationshipsController#edit - can't cast Hash to integer'

Comment: if i do find_by I get : NoMethodError in RelationshipsController#edit
undefined method `decorate' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @sss333 Check once i edited my answer, and also do you have followed_id in your user model. If possible please add your user attributes here

Comment: how do I know when you've finished editing the answer? I have it with the find_by edit included. added user model into original question

Comment: @sss333 Yes that is it, Did you try that, and please add your user attributes(fields)

Comment: i get: I get : NoMethodError in RelationshipsController#edit undefined method `decorate' for nil:NilClass

what are my user attribute fields? I added the model code for the user? i've just added the columns for user as well if that's what you mean?

Comment: that worked! cheers! why does follower_id work and not followed_id? (because you have to use the foreign key?)

Comment: @sss333 Nice.. Yes to query the db you must have field in that table right so you have field name as `follower_id` but not `followed_id` so you got error.

Comment: just checking everything. if i now go to press accept relationship i again get :NoMethodError in RelationshipsController#edit
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
 @relationship = current_user.pending_relationships.find_by(follower_id: @followed.id).decorate

when one part works the other fails? not sure why?

Comment: @sss333 please add your controller so I can Identify where it goes wrong

Comment: @sss333 Actually when you click on accept relationship it needs to call `accept` method instead of `edit` right but again you are redirecting to `edit`

Comment: it does call accept? 'if @relationship.accept!'? it redirects to relationships/index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64461/discussion-between-gowri-and-sss333).

Answer (score 0):

It was saying, with the params[:id] no active_relationships exists for the current user.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean by this @pooja agarwal?

Comment: current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]) is nil. Thats why it's showing undefined method 'decorate' for nil class.

Comment: you mean the pending_relationships? (active is commented out)
why is it saying nil? I have a pending relationship in the database. how do i make it not nil?

Comment: check with @followed is that id having any data in the table.